# async call for avatar in listitem of react-native-elements

Tags: react-native

I need to go grab users profile avatar by making an async call but I am getting an error. Does anyone know how to do this in react-native-elements?

```
someAsyncToGetUserProfile = () => {
   this.props.getUserAvatarUrl().then(doc =>
      return doc.photoUrl
  );
}
.
.
.
<ListItem
   avatar={this.someAsyncToGetUserProfile}
/>
```

Comment: From the snippet you provided I am not realy sure what are you trying to do here. Is it a list of users or the `ListItem` is just one data field for a current user?

Answer (score 0):

Await can be used only if the function declared as async.

```
someAsyncToGetUserProfile = async ()=>{
  let doc = await this.props.getUserAvatarUrl();
  return doc.photoUrl
}
```

.
.

```
<ListItem
   avatar={this.someAsyncToGetUserProfile()}
/>
```

Comment: In your code snippet, you have written `this.someAsyncToGetUserProfile` that will not call the function instead return the function itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I wasn't asking for how to make this an async await call. This method doesn't work.